# IOS JSON Parsing Containing Multiple Arrays

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I have a JSON array with multiple object and I don't know how do I grab the "url" tag as an NSArray or a NSDictionary and show that image url in CollectionView. I can't change the JSON data format.How should I do this?

**Here is what the JSON response looks like:**

```
   {
  "error": false,
  "data": [
    {
      "albumid": 2,
      "albumtitle": "Album 2",
      "images": [
        {
          "image": "Img2.jpeg",
          "imageid": 11
        },
        {
          "image": "vr4.jpg",
          "imageid": 4
        },
        {
          "image": "3purple b-ball.jpg",
          "imageid": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "albumid": 3,
      "albumtitle": "Album 3",
      "images": [
        {
          "image": "vr2.jpg",
          "imageid": 6
        },
        {
          "image": "vr1.jpg",
          "imageid": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "albumid": 4,
      "albumtitle": "Album 4",
      "images": [
        {
          "image": "vr1.jpg",
          "imageid": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "albumid": 12,
      "albumtitle": "My Album",
      "images": [
        {
          "image": "img3.jpeg",
          "imageid": 64
        },
        {
          "image": "img4.jpeg",
          "imageid": 63
        },
        {
          "image": "img5.jpeg",
          "imageid": 62
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "albumid": 13,
      "albumtitle": "Demo Album",
      "images": [
        {
          "image": "img6.jpeg",
          "imageid": 67
        },
        {
          "image": "img7.jpeg",
          "imageid": 66
        },
        {
          "image": "img11.jpeg",
          "imageid": 65
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you need to display image according to section as per you json structure.

Comment: Specify language also.

Comment: I m doing in Objective C @SakirSherasiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (data is the NSData object you get from your webserver):

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

if(!jsonError){
    NSArray *dataArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSDictionary *albumDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *imagesArray = [albumDict objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSDictionary *imageDict = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageURL = [imageDict objectForKey: @"image"];
}
```

Of course, you have to use loops for the array elements, this example is only with element 0. Some more checks if a field exists etc. would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model to hold the image id and url. You add an array of these image objects in the main model (Album). In Swift, your models might look like this

```
class Album {
    var albumId = ""
    var albumTitle = ""
    var albumImages = [AlbumImage]()
}

class AlbumImage {
    var imageId = ""
    var imageUrl = ""
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after downloaded the json file.

```
 NSDictionary *rootDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
 NSArray *rootArray = rootDict[@"data"];
 NSDictionary *subDict;
 NSArray *subArray;
 NSDictionary *tempDict;

 for (int i=0; i<rootArray.count; i++) {
     subDict = rootArray[i];
     subArray = subDict[@"images"];
     for (int j=0; j<subArray.count; j++) {
         tempDict = subArray[j];
         NSLog(@"%@",tempDict[@"image"]);
     }
 }
```

in JSONObjectSerialization **data** was NSData object where the json file downloaded.